# In R: Search all emails by subject line, pull comma-separate values from body, then save values in a dataframe

Tags: r, for-loop, outlook, rdcomclient

Each day, I get an email with the quantities of fruit sold on a particular day. The structure of the email is as below:

```
Date of report:,04-JAN-2022
Time report produced:,5-JAN-2022 02:04
Apples,6
Pears,1
Lemons,4
Oranges,2
Grapes,7
Grapefruit,2
```

I'm trying to build some code in R that will search through my emails, find all emails with a particular subject, iterate through each email to find the variables I'm looking for, take the values and place them in a dataframe with the "Date of report" put in a date column.

With the assistance of people in the community, I was able to achieve the desired result in Python. However as my project has developed, I need to now achieve the same result in R if at all possible.

Unfortunately, I'm quite new to R and therefore if anyone has any advice on how to take this forward I would greatly appreciate it.

For those interested, my Python code is below:

```
#PREP THE STUFF
Fruit_1 = "Apples"
Fruit_2 = "Pears"
searchf = [
    Fruit_1, 
    Fruit_2
]

#DEF THE STUFF
def get_report_vals(report, searches):
    dct = {}
    for line in report:
        term, *value = line
        if term.casefold().startswith('date'):
            dct['date'] = pd.to_datetime(value[0])
        elif term in searches:
            dct[term] = float(value[0])
    if len(dct.keys()) != len(searches):
    dct.update({x: None for x in searches if x not in dct})
return dct


#DO THE STUFF
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6) 
messages = inbox.Items
messages.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", True)

results = []

for message in messages:
    if message.subject == 'FRUIT QUANTITIES':
        if Fruit_1 in message.body and Fruit_2 in message.body:
            data = [line.strip().split(",") for line in message.body.split('\n')]
            results.append(get_report_vals(data, searchf))
        else:
            pass

fruit_vals = pd.DataFrame(results)
fruit_vals.columns = map(str.upper, fruit_vals.columns)
```

I'm probably going about this the wrong way, but I'm trying to use the steps I took in Python to achieve the same result in R. So for example I create some variables to hold the fruit sales I'm searching for, then I create a vector to store the searchables, and then when I create an equivalent 'get_vals' function, I create an empty vector.

```
library(RDCOMClient)

Fruit_1 <- "Apples"
Fruit_2 <- "Pears"
##Create vector to store searchables
searchf <- c(Fruit_1, Fruit_2)
## create object for outlook
OutApp <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")
outlookNameSpace = OutApp$GetNameSpace("MAPI")

search <- OutApp$AdvancedSearch("Inbox", "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject = 'FRUIT QUANTITIES'")
inbox <- outlookNameSpace$Folders(6)$Folders("Inbox")

vec <- c()

for (x in emails)
{
  subject <- emails(i)$Subject(1)
  if (grepl(search, subject)[1])
  {
    text <- emails(i)$Body()
    print(text)
    break
  }
}
```

Comment: You seem to be asking (at least) 3 separate questions - connecting to email, identifying the target emails, and parsing the identified emails. Which are you having problems with the most? Consider splitting this into multiple questions

Comment: I think my major issue is recreating the function (get_vals) due to the nature of vectors in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code now functions as intended. Function was written quite a bit differently from those recommended:

```
get_vals <- function(email) {
  body <- email$body()
  date <- str_extract(body, "\\d{2}-[:alpha:]{3}-\\d{4}") %>% 
    as.character()
  data <- read.table(text = body, sep = ",", skip = 9, strip.white = T) %>% 
    row_to_names(1) %>% 
    mutate("Date" = date)

  return(data)
}
```

In addition I've written this to bind the rows together:

```
info <- sapply(results, get_vals, simplify = F) %>% 
  bind_rows()
```

Answer (score 2):

`read.table` could be a good start for `get_report_vals`.
Code below outputs result as a list, exception handling still needs to be implemented :

```
report <- "
Date of report:,04-JAN-2022
Apples,6
Pears,1
Lemons,4
Oranges,2
Grapes,7
Grapefruit,2
"


get_report_vals <- function(report,searches) {
  data <- read.table(text=report,sep=",")
  colnames(data) <- c('key','value')

  # find date
  date <- data[grepl("date",data$key,ignore.case=T),"value"]
  
  # transform dataframe to list
  lst <- split(data$value,data$key)
  
  # output result as list
  c(list(date=date),lst[searches])
}

get_report_vals(report,c('Lemons','Oranges'))
$date
[1] "04-JAN-2022"

$Lemons
[1] "4"

$Oranges
[1] "2"
```

The results of various reports can then be concatenated in a `data.frame` using `rbind`:

```
rbind(get_report_vals(report,c('Lemons','Oranges')),get_report_vals(report,c('Lemons','Oranges')))
     date          Lemons Oranges
[1,] "04-JAN-2022" "4"    "2"    
[2,] "04-JAN-2022" "4"    "2"
```

Answer (score 0):

May this is not what you are expecting to get as an answer, but I must state that here to help other readers to avoid such mistakes in future.

Unfortunately your Python code is not well-written. For example, I've noticed the following code where you iterate over all items in a folder and check the `Subject` and message bodies for keywords:

```
for message in messages:
    if message.subject == 'FRUIT QUANTITIES':
        if Fruit_1 in message.body and Fruit_2 in message.body:
```

You need to use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the Items class instead. So, you don't need to iterate over all items in a folder. Instead, you get only items that correspond to your conditions. Read more about these methods in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

You may combine all your search criteria into a single query. So, you just need to iterate over found items and extract the data.

Also you may find the [AdvancedSearch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219884.aspx) method helpful. The key benefits of using the `AdvancedSearch` method in Outlook are:

- The search is performed in another thread. You don’t need to run another thread manually since the `AdvancedSearch` method runs it automatically in the background.
- Possibility to search for any item types: mail, appointment, calendar, notes etc. in any location, i.e. beyond the scope of a certain folder. The `Restrict` and `Find`/`FindNext` methods can be applied to a particular `Items` collection (see the `Items` property of the `Folder` class in Outlook).
- Full support for DASL queries (custom properties can be used for searching too). You can read more about this in the [Filtering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208216%28v=office.12%29) article in MSDN. To improve the search performance, Instant Search keywords can be used if Instant Search is enabled for the store (see the `IsInstantSearchEnabled` property of the `Store` class).
- You can stop the search process at any moment using the `Stop` method of the `Search` class.

See [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/) for more information.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for providing that. Why does that make it "badly written"? While the format of the email itself doesn't change, there have been various version of the email that I want to check for.

Comment: Iterating over all items in a folder is not really a good idea. The `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods should be used instead to optimize the Outlook performance.